# Arbitrary Counter only displaying zeros

Tags: verilog, counter, iverilog

I have to make an arbitrary counter for a determined sequence, and after making the transition table and the karnaugh maps, I was left with some equations that I turned into this Verilog program. It uses four JK bistable circuits.

However, when I execute, the program just prints 0's instead of the count I want, and I can't find why. I am sorry about the comments (I am Spanish).

```
//modulo del biestable JK
module biestableJK (output reg Q, output wire NQ, input wire J, input wire K,   input wire C);
  //hacemos Q negado, que es la salida secundaria del biestable JK
  not(NQ,Q);
  initial
  begin
    //inicializamos Q a 0
    Q='b0;
  end    
  //codificamos los biestables (por flanco de subida), y su modelo de comportamiento
  always @(posedge C)
    case ({J,K})
      2'b10: Q='b1; //set
      2'b01: Q='b0; //reset
      2'b11: Q=~Q;  //complemento
    endcase
endmodule


//modulo del contador
module contador (inout wire [3:0] Q, input wire C);
    //Declaramos arrays de tipo wire para poder almacenar la informacion que sale del llamamiento a los modulos de  biestable
    wire [3:0] QNEG; //salidas negadas
    wire [3:0] J; // entradas J
    wire [3:0] K; //entradas K

        //J3
            wire wireAND1J3, wireAND2J3;
        //K3
            wire wireAND1K3, wireAND2K3;

        //K1
            wire wireAND1K1, wireAND2K1;

        //J3
            and andJ3 (J[3], Q[0], QNEG[1]);

        //K3
            and andK3 (K[3], Q[0], Q[1]);

        //J2 y K2
            and andJK2 (J[2], Q[0], Q[1], Q[3]);

        //J1
            or orJ1 (J[1], Q[0], Q[3]);

        //K1
            and and1K1 (wireAND1K1, QNEG[0], QNEG[3]);
            and and2K1 (wireAND2K1, QNEG[2], QNEG[3]);
            and and3K1 (wireAND3K1, Q[0], Q[2], Q[3]);
            or orK1 (K[1], wireAND1K1, wireAND2K1, wireAND3K1);

        //J0 y K0
            and and1JK0 (wireAND1JK0, QNEG[1], QNEG[3]);
            and and2JK0 (wireAND2JK0, Q[1], Q[3]);
            and and3JK0 (wireAND3JK0, Q[1], Q[2]);
            or orJK0 (J[0], wireAND1J0, wireAND2J0, wireAND3J0);

    biestableJK JK3 (Q[3], QNEG[3], J[3], K[3], C);
    biestableJK JK2 (Q[2], QNEG[2], J[2], J[2], C);
    biestableJK JK1 (Q[1], QNEG[1], J[1], K[1], C);
    biestableJK JK0 (Q[0], QNEG[0], J[0], J[0], C);
    initial
       begin
       end
endmodule

//modulo de test
module test;
    wire [3:0] Q; //salidas de los biestables
    reg C; //reloj
    //llamada al modulo del contador (llamada al modulo) (nombre) (salidas Q, reloj)
    contador CONT (Q,C);
    //generamos elreloj: negamos C continuamente
    always #10 C=~C;
  //instrucciones para la ejecucion del modulo test 
  initial
  begin
    //declaramos la monitorizacion del cronograma y creamos 
    $dumpfile("cronograma.dmp"); 
    $dumpvars(1,CONT);
    $dumpon;
    C='b0;
    //sacamos por pantalla los resultados
    $monitor($time, " C=%b | Q=%d| Q=%b%b%b%b \n",C,Q,Q[3],Q[2],Q[1],Q[0]);
  //finalizamos la ejecucion a los 160 tics (hay 8 numeros y vamos a 10 tics por numero, asique hacemos dos ciclos)
  #160 $finish; 
  //se finaliza el cronograma
  $dumpoff; 
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I ran your simulation using Cadence's simulator, I got compile warnings like this:

```
            or orJK0 (J[0], wireAND1J0, wireAND2J0, wireAND3J0);
                                                             |
xmelab: *W,CSINFI : implicit wire has no fanin (test.CONT.wireAND3J0).
```

I got 1 warning for each "wireAND" signal in that line.  This means that you did not declare the `wireAND3J0` signal, which means that its value is `Z`.

Change:

```
    or orJK0 (J[0], wireAND1J0, wireAND2J0, wireAND3J0);
```

to:

```
    or orJK0 (J[0], wireAND1JK0, wireAND2JK0, wireAND3JK0);
```

Now, I get this output where `Q` is changing:

```
               0 C=0 | Q= 0| Q=0000
              10 C=1 | Q= 1| Q=0001
              20 C=0 | Q= 1| Q=0001
              30 C=1 | Q=10| Q=1010
              40 C=0 | Q=10| Q=1010
              50 C=1 | Q=11| Q=1011
              60 C=0 | Q=11| Q=1011
              70 C=1 | Q= 6| Q=0110
              80 C=0 | Q= 6| Q=0110
              90 C=1 | Q= 5| Q=0101
             100 C=0 | Q= 5| Q=0101
             110 C=1 | Q=14| Q=1110
             120 C=0 | Q=14| Q=1110
             130 C=1 | Q=15| Q=1111
             140 C=0 | Q=15| Q=1111
             150 C=1 | Q= 0| Q=0000
```

---

You can use simulators on edaplayground which might give you helpful messages like the one I showed.

If you use `$dumpvars;` (without arguments), you will get all signals in all modules in your VCD file.  I used that to see that `J` was unknown (`X`) inside the `biestableJK` module.